# React Native with RNFirebase Build Problem

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I'm having trouble in building iOS for react native app with [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/).

When I run the react-native run-ios, it starts the building procedure then prints this log:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DatingApp- hhnjjwfhinhhkbbhugkfimkvtfun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FIRAuth.o /Users/dev/Documents/Projects/DatingAndEventHosting_mobile-application/ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Auth/FIRAuth.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

[image]

Then I build with XCode, it fails with this error

```
No visible @interface for 'FIRUser' declares the selector 'sendEmailVerificationBeforeUpdatingEmail:actionCodeSettings:completion:'
```

[image]

[image]

Here is my package.json

[image]

And here is my Podfile

[image]

Could you please help. I tried to remove the node_modules and run all cache cleaning.

Comment: did you check by removing pods and reinstalling it agian ?

Comment: @AmilaDulanjana yes I remove all pods, the pod lock file. and run 'pod cache clean --all'

Comment: the same problem here

Comment: @TrungThai were you able to solve?